# Analyzer used to create Lucene index

Tags: java, lucene

I was wondering, given a Lucene index and nothing else, is there a way to recover what analyzer was used to create the index? If not, is there a way to tell which stemmer or stop words list was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Looking closely at the indexed data will likely allow you to draw some reasonable conclusions, but the index does not store that information directly.